# What does an algebra induced by $\mathcal{A}$ on a subset $E$ mean?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand what an algebra induced by $\mathcal{A}$ on a subset $E$ means.

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra of subsets of $X$

Let $E \subset X$

Let $\mathcal{A_E}$ be the algebra induced by $\mathcal{A}$ on $E$

Considering the set $X$ I defined above, could someone give me example values of $\mathcal{A}$, $E$ and $\mathcal{A_E}$ that would illustrate what an algebra induced by $\mathcal{A}$ on a subset $E$ means?

Comment: $\{ A \cap E : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$.

Comment: It is also called the trace algebra.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes that is how it is written in the book I'm reading. But I would like to see example values for the variables because I can't 'picture' it.

Comment: Sorry, but the only examples that come to mind without tediously constructing and verifying one, are trivial, so wouldn't help.